Claims in samlresponse to adfs OWA authentication
I have a problem while performing authentication in OWA using adfs and my own IDP.
The SAMLResponse from idp contains:
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Attribute FriendlyName="UPN" Name="UPN" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">admin
            </saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>

But im getting error in owa:
/owa/auth/errorfe.aspx?msg=UpnClaimMissing
with adfs-error:
x-adfserror: No UPN claim was found.
I have configured claim rules according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/outlook-on-the-web/ad-fs-claims-based-auth?view=exchserver-2019#step-2-deploy-an-ad-fs-server
with:
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid"), query = ";objectSID;{0}", param = c.Value);
and
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"), query = ";userPrincipalName;{0}", param = c.Value);
